# Is CFL closed against exchanging complementation and reversal?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Let $L$ be a language such that $\overline{L}^R$ (the reversal of the complement of $L$) is context-free. Is then also $\overline{(L^R)} \in \mathrm{CFL}$?

Comment: Are you sure your question has a meaning ? A family of languages can
be closed with respect to a given language transformation, such as
compementation, or such as reversal. You can also ask whether it is
closed with respect to their composition.  The only thing that would
seem to make sense in your case is asking whether the two
transformations commute when you restrict their application to CFL.
I do not see it as a closure issue.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Show that they are the same language.